# Can I factor a binomial coefficient out from an equation?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factoring

By the distributive property, if I'm given the equation XY + XZ

I can factor this to X(Y +Z).

I'm wondering if I could apply this same property to a binomial coefficient,

e.g., I'm given nCr(n, X) * Y + nCr(n, X) * Z

Could i factor this to nCr(n, X) * (Y + Z)

This is assuming that the value of n and X are the same respectively between the two binomial coefficients. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In the scenario you have described, yes, the result of a binomial coefficient calculation is just another value in the expression and can be factored out.

Comment: $XY+XZ = X(Y+Z)$.  This is true when $X$ is a simple number, when $X$ is a binomial coefficient, when $X$ is three children in a trench coat, or anything else that makes sense for $X$ to be so long as it is in a context where the distributive property applies

Comment: "Anything that multiplies both terms of a sum can be factored out, though I'm darned if I know what you mean by "nCr(n,X)"" -- OP is probably just using the notation a calculator is using and defining implicitly
$$
\text{nCr}(n,X) := \binom n X = \,_n C_X
$$
or whatever notation you might prefer.